# The multipart identifier could not be bound on Select columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am setting this stored procedure and I get this error :

> The multipart identifier could not be bound

on all the columns in select.

This is the query I have:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Ps_GetEquipeProjet] 
    @PROJET_ID INT = NULL,
    @RoleID INT = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @requete VARCHAR(250)
    SET @requete = (SELECT CleRepartition FROM EQUIPE_PROJET  
                    WHERE Projet_Id = @PROJET_ID AND Role_Id = 3 
                      AND CleRepartition IS NOT NULL) 

    SELECT 
        EP.Equipe_Projet_Id AS PROJET_ID,
        U.USR_ID, U.USR_NOM, U.USR_PRENOM,
        U.USR_LOGIN,
        RE.Role_Eq_Libelle AS ROLE_NOM,
        EP.CleRepartition = CASE
                               WHEN @RoleID = 1 AND @requete IS NOT NULL AND @requete = 75 
                                  THEN 25 
                               WHEN @RoleID = 1 AND @requete IS NOT NULL AND @requete = 50 
                                  THEN 50 
                               WHEN @RoleID = 2 AND @requete IS NOT NULL 
                                  THEN 20
                               ELSE NULL      
                            END   
    FROM 
        [EQUIPE_PROJET] EP
    INNER JOIN 
        UTILISATEUR U ON  U.USR_ID = EP.[User_Id]
    INNER JOIN 
        Ref_Role_Eq RE ON RE.Role_Eq_Id = EP.[Role_Id] 
    WHERE 
        (@PROJET_ID IS NULL OR @PROJET_ID = EP.[Projet_Id]) 
        AND EP.Deletion_Date IS NULL
        AND (@RoleID IS NULL OR [Role_Id] = @RoleID)
END
```

Comment: Please give us the full error, not a snippet of it. Thanks.

Comment: Also, you have a trailing equals on one of your columns `EP.CleRepartition=`. I assume that should be `EP.CleRepartition,`?

Comment: EP.CleRepartition will have the value depending on cases.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, `EP.CleRepartition` can't have a value dependant on the `CASE` expression; you can't `UPDATE` a table in the same statement you perform `SELECT` from it that *returns* a dataset. If you need to update the value of `EP.CleRepartition` you need to use a **separate** `UPDATE` statement

Comment: Explains why I recognised this, @SMor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in the comments, you can't `UPDATE` a column in the same statement you are returning a dataset with a `SELECT` to the presentation layer. You'll need to `UPDATE` the value of `CleRepartition` first, and then perform your `SELECT`. I can't test this, but at a guess, perhaps this is what you need:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Ps_GetEquipeProjet] @PROJET_ID int = NULL,
                                           @RoleID int = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @requete varchar(250);
    SET @requete = (SELECT CleRepartition
                    FROM EQUIPE_PROJET
                    WHERE Projet_Id = @PROJET_ID
                      AND Role_Id = 3
                      AND CleRepartition IS NOT NULL);

    UPDATE EP
    SET CleRepartition = CASE
                              WHEN @RoleID = 1
                               AND @requete IS NOT NULL
                               AND @requete = 75 THEN 25
                              WHEN @RoleID = 1
                               AND @requete IS NOT NULL
                               AND @requete = 50 THEN 50
                              WHEN @RoleID = 2
                               AND @requete IS NOT NULL THEN 20
                              ELSE NULL
                         END
    FROM [EQUIPE_PROJET] EP
         INNER JOIN UTILISATEUR U ON U.USR_ID = EP.[User_Id]
         INNER JOIN Ref_Role_Eq RE ON RE.Role_Eq_Id = EP.[Role_Id]
    WHERE (@PROJET_ID IS NULL
        OR @PROJET_ID = EP.[Projet_Id])
      AND EP.Deletion_Date IS NULL
      AND (@RoleID IS NULL
        OR [Role_Id] = @RoleID);


    SELECT EP.Equipe_Projet_Id AS PROJET_ID,
           U.USR_ID,
           U.USR_NOM,
           U.USR_PRENOM,
           U.USR_LOGIN,
           RE.Role_Eq_Libelle AS ROLE_NOM,
           EP.CleRepartition
    FROM [EQUIPE_PROJET] EP
         INNER JOIN UTILISATEUR U ON U.USR_ID = EP.[User_Id]
         INNER JOIN Ref_Role_Eq RE ON RE.Role_Eq_Id = EP.[Role_Id]
    WHERE (@PROJET_ID IS NULL
        OR @PROJET_ID = EP.[Projet_Id])
      AND EP.Deletion_Date IS NULL
      AND (@RoleID IS NULL
        OR [Role_Id] = @RoleID);
END;

GO
```

On a different note, what you have here is known as a "Catch-all query", or (as Aaron Bertrand calls it) a "kitchen sink" query. Really, you want to be using dynamic SQL for such queries, or `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` (personally I go with the former). here's a few articles to read from Gail Shaw and Bertrand on the subject: [Catch-All Queries](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/), [Revisiting Catch-All Queries](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2018/03/13/revisiting-catch-all-queries/) and [#BackToBasics: An Updated "Kitchen Sink" Example](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example)

Comment: Thank you Larnu. It's working.

Comment: the first time the procedure is excuted it's working. The second time it make  all column CleRepartition NULL

Comment: Not surprising, as `25 != 1`. That's the logic you asked for though.

Comment: I did not understand. where 25 how to fix it?

Comment: I don't know, as I've only shown you what you've asked for. You need to understand and support it. If you don't understand it, then you need to ask about that.